# toProperCase Javascript Regex - include hypen etc

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the below function (first one) to change the case of some text, which is great. But I would like it to take into consideration letters following a hypen apos etc. Can anyone help me modify it to include this? I've been able to do the second function, but I'm sure you must be able to put this in the regex?

```
function toProperCase(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}

//don't want to do it like this;
function toProperCase(str)
{
    str = str.replace("-", "- ");
    str = str.replace("'", "' ");
    str = str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
    str = str.replace("- ", "-");
    str = str.replace("' ", "'");
    return str;
}
```

Comment: yeah regex should be able to do it, not my forte so can't really help but you know you can chain your replace call like this str = str.replace("-", "- ").replace("'", "' ").replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}).replace("- ", "-").replace("' ", "'");

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you?

```
str.replace(/\w*/g, function(txt){
                       return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
                              txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will work better for your use case:

```
str.replace(/\b[a-z][\w'-]*/ig, function(txt){
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
               txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
     }
);
```

This is basically finding all the words where first character is an alphabet and it is followed by a word character or a hyphen or a apos.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toProperCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\b./g, 
           function(txt){return txt.toUpperCase()}
           )
    }
```

This finds each character which is preceded by a word boundary and replaces it with its uppercase version.

A word boundary is the position at the start and end of the string, and the position between a word character and a non-word character. A word character is a letter, digit or underscore and a non-word character is everything else.

You're not very specific about "hyphen, apostrophe, etc" so I'm guessing that it applies to anything which is not a letter, digit or underscore.

Note that you don't have to subdivide your found string or add a lowercase string, because `replace` replaces only the character(s) which match: in this case that's a single character.